# Android .JPG is not saving to the SD card

Tags: android, image

Im trying to capture user signature and store it under SD Card. App runs without any error.But the image file is not storing to the SD card.it only shows folder named sign.jpg.
Image is missing .please help me to slove this. im new to android..
Here is my current  code

```
    public Bitmap save(View v) {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
        Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
        if (mBitmap == null) {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(),
                    mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        try {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            v.draw(canvas);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);

            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                mBitmap, "title", null);
            Log.v("log_tag", "url: " + url);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
        }
        return mBitmap;
    }
```

Logcat displays this error message

```
    09-16 17:11:52.517: E/BitmapFactory(1123): Unable to decode stream:   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/Captures/sign1945.jpg: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

Comment: Please remove most of that code. Don't dump that here all. Post only relevant code.

Comment: please add only the code you using for save.

Comment: sorry for the mistake..now its edited.

Comment: Please give an example of the value of `mypath`. Is it your intention that there is a `folder named sign.jpg` ?

Comment: here is it /data/data/com.bapos.android.driver/app_GetSignature/20140916_164636_0.14522239811218363.png

Comment: Please explain what you ment with `folder named sign.jpg`? I asked that already.

Comment: no that jpg file name is sign<som number>.jpg and it is blank..above line is mypath.tostring()

Comment: What is the type of 'mypath' ? What do you mean with 'sign'? Do I have to conclude now that `20140916_164636_0.145222398‌​11218363.png`  is a folder instead of a file? And what is 'blank'? I cannot follow you. Please be exact.

Comment: when i open file explorer app in android and navigate to that folder it shows bunch of files named sing345.jpg,sign498.jpg etc..but all of these image files does not have anything..

Comment: mypath is file..File mypath;

Comment: But that is completely different from what you just told about the value of 'mypath'. How is that possible? Please explain in detail as i cannot follow this. And explain why you called sign.jpg a folder. And with a file explorer you cannot navigate to  /data/data/.... as that is internal memory.

Comment: in file explorer its displays like a folder.not like a image.. i have open DDMS also and it shows that files as folders..sorry for the confusion..

Comment: yes i have put logcat out put to show mypath..but i think my tab is a rooted one.

Comment: in logcat it shows this error  E/BitmapFactory(1123): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/Captures/sign1945.jpg: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in `mypath` variable

-be sure to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` to get the SD Card path

-you need to tell the `compress` method : hey i want to save bitmap to this directory with this name! like this:

```
//saveDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/folder/";
File file = new File(saveDirectoryPath);
if (!file.exists())
    file.mkdir();  //or file.mkdirs(); depends on your need
File bitmapFile = new File(file, "yourImageFileName.jpg");
FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(bitmapFile);
mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
```

Comment: this is how i get the path..is it wrong..                         ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
  File directory = cw.getDir(
    getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir),
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  prepareDirectory();
  uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_"
    + Math.random();
  current = uniqueId + ".png";
  mypath = new File(directory, current);

Comment: instead of getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) use :
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

Comment: i have  chaged that in to File directory =new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());   but still no luck..i dont know wht to do